# ¿Como puedo imprimir una actividad en forma de tarjeta con un formulario enviando los datos a un PHP?

Tags: php, html, formularios

Es una actividad de la FP de DAW de la asignatura de Desarrollo Web en entornos del servidor. En principio, en el ejemplo del profesor solo se ha usado PHP y HTML/CSS.

Tengo tres archivos diferentes, un fichero PHP, un formulario en HTML y un objeto creado en otro archivo PHP. Me piden usar el formulario para recoger los datos, y una vez hecho, imprimir esos datos en forma de tarjeta al lado del mismo formulario. EL problema es que al enviar los datos al objeto se abre el fichero actividad.php y no se visualiza nada.

No sé si hay algún fallo en el código o es que es necesario algo más.

Si me pudieran ayudar se lo agradecería, muchas gracias.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
    <title>Formulario</title>
  </head>
  <body>
      <div class="card-group">
          
      
        <form method="post" action="actividad.php">
          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="Actividad">Actividad</label>
              <input id="Actividad" class="form-control" type="text" name="titulo">
          </div>

          <br>

          <div class="form-group">
              <label for="fecha"></label>
              <input id="fecha" class="form-control" type="date" name="fecha">
          </div>

          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="ciudad">Ciudad</label>
            <input id="ciudad" class="form-control" type="text" name="ciudad">
          </div>

          <br>

          <div class="form-group">
            <select id="tipo" class="form-control" name="tipo">
              <option selected>Selecione un tipo</option>
                      <option value="Música">Música</option>
                      <option value="Cine">Cine</option>
                      <option value="Comida">Comida</option>
                      <option value="Copas">Copas</option>
                      <option value="Cultura">Cultura</option>
                      <option value="Viajes">Viajes</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          
          <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="precio" id="flexRadioDefault1">
            <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault1">
              GRATIS
            </label>
          </div>
          <div class="form-check">
            <input class="form-check-input" type="radio" name="precio" id="flexRadioDefault2" checked>
            <label class="form-check-label" for="flexRadioDefault2">
              DE PAGO
            </label>
          </div>

            <div class="d-grid gap-2 col-6 mx-auto">
              <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit">Guardar Actividad</button>
            </div>
          

         
        </form>
      </div>

      <!-- Optional JavaScript; choose one of the two! -->

      <!-- Option 1: Bootstrap Bundle with Popper -->
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

      <!-- Option 2: Separate Popper and Bootstrap JS -->
      <!--
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/@popperjs/core@2.10.2/dist/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-7+zCNj/IqJ95wo16oMtfsKbZ9ccEh31eOz1HGyDuCQ6wgnyJNSYdrPa03rtR1zdB" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-QJHtvGhmr9XOIpI6YVutG+2QOK9T+ZnN4kzFN1RtK3zEFEIsxhlmWl5/YESvpZ13" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
      -->



   
  </body>
</html>
```

titulo = $titulo;
            $this-> tipo = $tipo;
            $this-> fecha = $fecha;
            $this-> ciudad = $ciudad;
            $this-> precio = $precio;
          
        }


        
    }

?>

```
<?php require "actividad.php";
if(isset($_POST['crearActividad']))
    {
        $actividad = new Actividad($_POST["titulo"],
                                    $_POST["tipo"],
                                    $_POST["fecha"],
                                    $_POST["ciudad"],
                                    $_POST["precio"]);
    }

?>

<html lang="es">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Formulario DESARROLLO WEB ENTORNO SERVIDOR</title>
    <link href="style.css" type="text/css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <header>
            
            <h1>ACTIVIDADES RECREATIVA</h1>
            
        </header>
        
        <div class="card">
            <?php if(isset($actividad)):?>
                
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">
                        <?php echo $actividad->titulo?>
                    </div>
                    <?php if($actividad->tipo !== ""):?>
                        <div class="card">
                            <img class="card-img-top" src="./img/<?php echo $actividad->tipo; ?>.jpg" alt="">
                        </div>
                    <?php endif?>
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <ul class="list-group list-group-flush">
                                <li class="list-group-item"><?php echo $actividad->fecha;?></li>
                                <li class="list-group-item"><?php echo $actividad->ciudad;?></li>
                                <li class="list-group-item"><?php echo $actividad->precio;?></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                    

                </div>

            <?php endif?>
        </div>
        <div>
           <?php include "formularios.html"?>
        </div>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: ¿Usas el formulario para recoger datos y mandarlos al servidor para obtener otros datos? Si es así, convendría que uses Ajax o la nueva API Fetch de Javascript, previniendo que el formulario se envíe al modo tradicional (que es recargando la página). Por el contrario, si no necesitas nada del servidor a posteriori, puedes actualizar tu contenido desde Javascript.

Comment: Es una actividad de la FP de DAW. Me piden usar el formulario para recoger los datos, y una vez hecho, imprimir esos datos en forma de tarjeta al lado del mismo formulario. Gracias por la respuesta.

Comment: En ese caso puedes usar Javascript (si te es permitido en el contexto del ejercicio) para recoger dichos datos y presentarlos. Si es un ejercicio indica en la pregunta qué te permiten y qué no y qué se requiere (por ejemplo, se debe evitar que la página se recargue, etc).

Comment: En principio en el ejemplo del profesor solo utilizó PHP y HTM con CSS, porque es de la asignatura de "Desarrollo en entorno del servidor", pero no hay ningún tipo de limitación.

Comment: Viendo que en tu segundo archivo php tienes un `require actividad.php`, y viendo el código de los archivos... tu formulario no debería apuntar al archivo que contiene el HTML y no a `actividad.php` que asumo que es el que dices que solo crea un objeto?? El cual además, lo estás requiriendo en el otro archivo. `action="actividad.php"` -> No sé cómo se llama tu otro archivo, pero imagino que debería ir ahí, y no actividad.php

Comment: Muchas gracias, si que era eso.

Comment: Además de eso, hacia falta añadir la etiqueta de "name" al boton hecho en html para que enviase la información con el método post al archivo index.php